# SurrealDB - How to store record linkage in Rust struct?

Tags: rust, struct, serde, surrealdb

There is an example in [SurrealDB documentation](https://surrealdb.com/docs/integration/sdks/rust) about using Rust's structs to store received data:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Name<'a> {
    first: &'a str,
    last: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Person<'a> {
    title: &'a str,
    name: Name<'a>,
    marketing: bool,
}
```

I couldn't find an example about storing a Record in a struct. Should I use `Thing` or create a struct called `Record` with `id` field?

For example this is the database schema I use and I want to store the select result of a `notification` table as a struct:

**Schema.surql:**

```
DEFINE TABLE notification SCHEMAFULL;

DEFINE FIELD content ON notification TYPE string;
DEFINE FIELD user_id ON notification TYPE record(user);
```

**Notification Struct**:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Notification {
    content: String,
    user_id: TYPE_HERE, <= ???
}
```

What is the **type to store record linkage** in Rust?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put id: Option<Thing>, its from use surrealdb::sql::Thing;

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Person<'a> {
  id: Option<Thing>
  title: &'a str,
  name: Name<'a>,
  marketing: bool,
}
```

When you save it to db, and you want auto id, you put id None and set table name only, no table id.

```
let data = Person {
  id: None, title, name, marketing
}
let table_name = "test";
let result = db.create(table_name).content(data).await?;
```

OR if you want to set an id to it:

```
let data_to_save = Person {
  id: None, title, name, marketing
}
let table_name = "test";
let person_id = "person_id";
let dbData: Option<Person> = db.update((table_name, 
  person_id)).merge(data_to_save ).await?;
```

It will save to db with tb:test, id: person_id.

Answer (score -1):

According to DEFINE FIELD docs and Record IDs

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/define/field

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/datamodel/ids

I think you are supposed to put the type of the `Record id` for `user` table.

Comment: Yes, I know I need to use Record type in SurrealDB. I'm asking about usage of the Record type in Rust. Can you give a Rust Struct example?